# Randomly pairing a set of positive integers with limits on the difference of paired values

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Given a set $A$ containing all positive integers up to and including $n$:
$$
A = \{1, 2, 3, \dots,n-1,n\}
$$
I'm looking for a way to randomly pair up each number in $A$ (with one integer left over if $n$ is odd) to create a set of pairs $P$ such that:

1. The difference between the values in each pair is always 2 or less, i.e. $|i-j|\le 2$ for any pair $(i,j)$ in $P$.
2. Each of the $2n-3$ possible pairs permitted by the previous condition have a roughly equal probability of appearing in $P$.

For example if $n=7$, then
$$
A = \{1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}
$$
and one possible set of parings $P$ which satisfies the requirements is
$$
P = \{(1,3),\, (2,4),\, (6,7)\}
$$

It seems to me like a good starting point would be to try to sample uniformly from the set of all possible sets $P$, and check to see if this satisfies condition (2).

A brute-force way would be to actually construct the full set containing all possible $P$, and sample from in uniformly, but I imagine this set would get very large as $n$ grows (and I also have no idea how to construct it).

Does anyone have ideas on how to approach this?

Thanks!

---

Based on Gerry's suggestion I wrote the following Python function to construct a random $P$:

```
def recursive_sample(n):
    A = [i for i in range(n)]
    P = []
    # randomise which end we start from
    if randint(2): A.reverse()
    # build pairs until we run out of integers
    while len(A) > 0:
        if randint(2) and len(A)>3:
            P.append((A[-1],A[-3]))
            P.append((A[-2],A[-4]))
            A = A[:-4]
        else:
            P.append((A[-1],A[-2]))
            A = A[:-2]
    return P
```

It's very simple, which is great, but it doesn't quite solve the problem fully as some of the possible pairings never appear in $P$. Here is the chance of each possible pair appearing in $P$ over 25000 runs with $n=8$:

[image]

You can see that some of the pairs on the first off-diagonal (which should appear as the difference between the pair values is only 1 there) are never selected, such as (2,3) and (4,5).

I'm trying to figure out some way to augment this approach so the missing pairs do appear in $P$ - if anyone has thoughts please let me know!

Comment: "Randomly" is probably less precise than you want. (For example, always pairing $2k+1$ with $2k$ is random; or, if you like, flip a coin between $\{(1,2),(3,4)\}$ and $\{(1,3),(2,4)\}$ and leave the rest alone.) Are you wanting to choose each possible pairing with positive probability? with equal probability?

Comment: +1 : nicely discussed - this problem has depth, since you want to avoid brute force.  the problem is that given a middle value $k$, where you are going to select one of $\{(k-2), (k-1), (k+1), (k+2)\}$, you are going to have to **analyze** when this leads to **blockage** = being unable to fulfill the requirements because of previous choices.  You have 3 options here: (1) First use brute force to identify all possible satisfying sets of pairings.  (2) **Somehow** diagnose when blockages occur mathematically and program your software appropriately - this may be very difficut. ...see next comment

Comment: (3) Program complex software to use **backtracking** = when the software diagnoses blockage, retract last move, try again, until next blockage.  If retracting one move fails, retract two moves.  If retract one move works, and you encounter next blockage, repeat retraction algorithm at new point.  This approach has your software do **all the heavy lifting.**

Comment: @GregMartin quite right! I'll make an edit to clarify. What I'd like is that when we choose some particular set of pairs $P$, that any of the possible individual pairs which are allowed by the condition have a (roughly) equal probability to appear in $P$. It's not clear to me if giving equal probability to every possible $P$ and choosing one satisfies this, but that's something I could test if I had a way to do that sampling.

Comment: @user2661923 I've tried coding up a few ideas and ran into the kind of problems you're describing, where for example in some cases I'm unable to construct the last pair because the two numbers remaining differ by more than 2. I might check how the success rate varies as $n$ grows, and if it remains reasonably high I could potentially just re-run the code until it succeeds, and see if that gives good enough sampling uniformity. If the success rate drops a lot, then either diagnosing or backtracking from blockages as you suggest may be the only way to go.

Comment: As a refinement of the blocked approach, I recommend that your software identify the blockage point, and retract moves until this specific point is *unblocked*.  For example, if $n = 50$ and you are left with a blockage re (for example) points $17$ and $40$, then your software needs to retract until one of $\{15,16,18,19\}$ is freed **and** one of $\{38,39,41,42\}$ is freed.

Comment: Seems to me there's a simple recurrence here. You have to pair $n$ with $n-1$ or $n-2$. If you pair $n$ with $n-1$, you're left with the problem of pairing $\{\,1,2,\dots,n-2\,\}$. If you pair $n$ with $n-2$, then you have to pair $n-1$ with $n-3$, and then pair off $\{\,1,2,\dots,n-4\,\}$. So, if $a_n$ is the number of ways to pair up $\{\,1,2,\dots,n\,\}$, then $a_n=a_{n-2}+a_{n-4}$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I thought the same, but then I remembered that $n$ might not be paired with anything if $n$ is odd, and $n-1$ might not be paired with anything if $n$ is odd and paired with $n-2$. So the recurrence is a bit more complicated, but still probably amenable to analysis. In particular, I definitely recommend to the OP to start from one end, rather than the middle, when trying to construct random examples.

Comment: @Greg, right you are. But anyway the recurrence should work for $n$ even.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I had a go at implementing your suggestion and it gets close to solving to problem but some of the possible pairings do not appear. There may be some modification that could be made which fixes that though... I'll edit the post and show the results of the testing!

Comment: When $n=8$, $2$ can't pair with $3$ – what would $1$ pair with? Similarly, $4$ can't pair with $5$, because that leaves no way to pair off $1,2,3$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Ah of course... that's very interesting. Doesn't this mean that satisfying the requirement about each possible pair appearing with roughly equal probability is impossible to satisfy? If so I may need to look into generating fewer pairs than the maximum possible amount in order to satisfy it.

Comment: By the way, for $n=8$, there are only five possible pairings, so it's a bit silly to do 25,000 runs. The only possibilities are 12/34/56/78, 12/34/57/68, 12/35/46/78, 13/24/56/78, and 13/24/57/68.

Comment: If $n$ is even, then $a_n$ is a Fibonacci number: $a_2=1$, $a_4=2$, $a_6=3$, $a_8=5$, and so on. If $n$ is odd than $a_n$ is given by the sequence at http://oeis.org/A023610 ($a_1=1$, $a_3=3$, $a_5=7$, $a_7=15$, $a_9=30$ and so on).